# How to use asp:HyperlinkField and javascript in asp.net instead of plain html hyperlink and javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, hyperlink

I am trying to replace the plain html hyperlink and javascript with asp:hyperlink and javascript. the "return javascript();" function does not work in asp:hyperlink column. Please help me with this. My plain html link is below I want to replace it with asp:hyperlink

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return fn_Edit_Customer(<%# Eval("CustomerID") %>);" target="_blank" title="Click here to Edit" style=" text-decoration:underline; color:Blue; cursor:hand;"  >Edit</a>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

i WANT TO put something like below

```
<asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Edit" Text="Edit"  NavigateURL="javascript:fn_editCustomer({0})"  Target="_blank"  />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `OnClick="fn_editCustomer({0});"` - and always accept an answers if it helped you, or people will **stop** helping you..

Comment: hi pocha, the OnClick= event on asp:hyperlinkfield is a server side event and won't function on clientside and I can't put it on <asp:hyperlink field. Is there anything I can put on navigateurl or navigateurlformatstring field or something?

Comment: @Enggr `asp:hyperlinkfield` (nor `asp:hyperlink` for that matter) does **not** have an `onclick` event at all (server or client side) - in fact, VS will actually complain that it is an unknown attribute, but just ignore it, the resulting anchor (`<a />`) will keep it - try it out first next time before you assume anything...